# Keycloak login based Authorization and authentication of application user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, authentication, keycloak

I am new to keycloak , whether the user creation should be happened in my application or at keycloak

Answer (score 0):

User creation can happen in Keycloak self when you are logged in as the master.

Check this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9O99l4gjAc
This is an example of a spring boot application with Keycloak and OAuth2.0

Hopefully it helps you with your use cases/project

Answer (score 0):

All user management tasks are done in Keycloack